# How can I install this node.js binary/module?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to use [this xml parser](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-o3-fastxml) but there's absolutely no information on how to install it. It doesn't seem available on `npm`, and I haven't come across any good instructions through google.

I'm on Debian 5 Lenny, and relatively new to node.js. Someone mentioned to append the `NODE_PATH` environment variable, but I'm not sure how I should structure it, in terms of choosing **WHERE** to store my node binaries.

Can someone provide a **full example** demonstration of setting it up? Including `git clone`ing if necessary.

PS - I'd like multiple users to use these modules so I don't just want to put this in `~` for myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, what you need to do is the following

1. Open `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Add the line `export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"` to the end of the file

**Note:** If you edit the file with a graphical program always use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` otherwise you may end up with files that are not root's being owned by root

Now Node will search for modules in `/usr/local/lib/node` (create it if it doesn't exist, also you need to start a new bash since bashrc is only read on start), next step is to put the stuff there.

1. Get the repo, either by downloading it or cloning it
2. Copy the `o3-fastxml` folder from `node-o3-fastxml/lib` into `/usr/local/lib/node`, so that you have a `/usr/local/lib/node/o3-fastxml` folder
3. Make sure the files are owned by root but can be read by everyone else

Last step, require the module in Node and check whether everything is working:

```
require('o3-fastxml') //magic! Gnah, Node will find the folder o3-fastxml on the path and will then find the index.js inside the folder
```

That should be all that's needed, if I'm not mistaken :)

Just leave a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. The process was perfect, but the library seems to be broken in node 0.2.5: `Error: /usr/local/lib/node/o3-fastxml/o3-lin64.node: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. I'm gonna try libxmljs.

Comment: Hm runs fine here on Ubuntu10.04 32bit with Node 3.1-pre, seems to be a problem with the compiled binary not working under Lenny, always bad when there's no source code available :/

Comment: If you have multiple versions of node installed, make sure you are compiling o3 against the 0.2.5 version.  I had this issue and it turns out I was compiling against node master.  It will not load into 0.2.5 in that case.